# Django loop display

Tags: python, django

I am doing a modal in Django for person detail and is all in a loop, but I am getting only the first person from the list in modal even if I click on a different person. It could be my loops but can't think clearly. Example:

```
<tbody>
      {% if orders %}
      {% for order in orders %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{order.order_id}}</th>
          <td>{{ order.product |capfirst }}</td>        
          <td>{{ order.units}}</td>   
          <td>{{ order.quantity}}</td>
          <td>{{ order.date}}</td>
          <td>{{ order.supplier}}</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">{{order.user}}</button></td>         
        </tr>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ order.user }}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p><em>{{ order.user.position }}</em></p>
                <p><em>{{ order.user.email }}</em></p>
                <p><em>{{ order.user.dob }}</em></p>
                <p><em>{{ order.user.phone }}</em></p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">          
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>There are no orders.</h2>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </tbody>
```

Example: I have clicked on Dan Jink but I got Martin Lawrence
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same id `exampleModal` for each order.
Try to generate some unique modal id for each order. In this example I modified your code to use `exampleModal` + `order.user.id` as a unique identifier:

```
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{order.user.id}}">{{order.user}}</button></td>         
  </tr>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{order.user.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel{{order.user.id}}" aria-hidden="true">
```

And do the same for `exampleModalLabel`.

Comment: you are legend! great eye!